# javascript Firebug error: Identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Tags: javascript, function, firebug

I've got this error being reported in firebug, but I have no idea what it means:

Identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Here is my webpage:
http://www.austintreeexperts.com/maps/optionUpdateMap.cfm?zoom=15

When the page and map loads, click on one of the blue or green markers.  Then click on one of the check boxes to get the error.  I have an onclick= for the input checkboxes.

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question,

Comment: Firefox and firebug version you are using, please.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your string concatenation is broken. You need to wrap your method parameters in quotes

```
var statusForm = '<input id="tU'+Aid+'" type="checkbox" onclick="optionAUpdate(tU'+Aid+', '+color+', '+optionB+')"/> option A  |  <input id="iU'+Aid+'" onclick="optionBUpdate(iU'+Aid+', '+color+', '+optionA+')" type="checkbox"/> options B';
From here ----------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

**Corrected version**

```
var statusForm = '<input id="tU' + Aid + '" type="checkbox" onclick="optionAUpdate(\'tU' + Aid + '\', \'' + color + '\', \'' + optionB + '\')"/> option A'
```

**Note** : I've treated all your params as strings

Comment: Wow, did you extract that from his source? Way to go the extra mile, I'd +2 you if I could. That said, you did not correct the code in the posted example, correct? It doesn't appear to be right.

Comment: @JAAulde thanks, was easy with firebug :). You're right, I should post the corrected version as well. updating

Answer (score 2):

This message also appears if you've tried to name a variable starting with a numeral. eg.

```
var 2ndString = 'abc';
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16327374)

Comment: @Pau I don't understand why I was downvoted. If you have the error message "Identifier starts immediately after numeric literal", it might be because you tried to name a variable starting with a number.

Is this not helpful for people who land here because they searched "Identifier starts immediately after numeric literal"?

Comment: Ah, sorry Pau :)

Answer (score 1):

Your onclick needs to be:

```
optionAUpdate('tU20238', '75AB5F', 0)
```

Note that I wrapped the params in quotes as they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input 
    id="is-ib-checkbox" 
    value='+accWidgetData[count]["userAccountNumber"]+' 
    onchange="addaUserAccount(\'' + accWidgetData[count]["userAccountNumber"] + '\' );"  
    value="true" 
    checked="checked" 
    type="checkbox" 
    />
```

Answer (score -2):

For this case, in my code:

```
html.input()
       .onclick("selectItem(" +"'"+cons.getIdentificacion().toString()+"'" + ");")
       .type("radio")
       .name("selectedItem")
       .style("vertical-align: text-bottom")
       .close();
```

works Fine.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be native Javascript - what is this? It doesn't look valid to me...