# Does javascript/jquery "hate" negative number as part of id name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-concatenation

I have a snippet of JQuery code that do some bar scrolling.

Since I have three, four, ... *n* bar to slide into my PHP page, I assign them dinamically an *id* and pass it to JQuery for be sure that my snippet slide the correct bar on a mouseOver event.

That's the snippet of code that do the "inizialization" of my scrolls

```
(function($){
 $.fn.horizontalScroll = function(options) {

 var rid = arguments[0];
 var oid = arguments[1];

 var defaults = { };

 var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

 return this.each(function() {

            var horiz_scroll = new dw_scrollObj($(this).attr('id'), $(this).children().attr('id'), $(this).children().children().attr('id'));
            horiz_scroll.setUpScrollbar("dragBar_"+rid+"_offer_"+oid, "track_"+rid+"_offer_"+oid, "h", 1, 1);
            horiz_scroll.setUpScrollControls('scrollbar_'+rid+'_offer_'+oid);
```

As you can see, `"dragBar_"+rid+"_offer_"+oid` dinamically concatenates my id(s) to other string part.

That's fine and all goin' well, except when my `oid` became something like `-1`

In that case I have an error that says

> identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

That's confuse me, because i've read on StackOverflow some questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883397/javascript-firebug-error-identifier-starts-immediately-after-numeric-literal) (just a random one) and I expect that behaviour for **all** concatenation that involves number.

That the snippet of code where all "breaks"

```
this.timerId = setInterval(this.animString + ".scroll()", 10);
```

Where `this.animString` is `"dw_scrollObj.col.horiz_container_outer_55_offer_-1"` while in other case (where it works) is `"dw_scrollObj.col.horiz_container_outer_62_offer_234"`

Anyone can explain me why this happen?

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: @ThiefMaster : this is a JQuery snippet of code from third part .. I took it as it comes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to access a global variable named `dw_scrollObj.col.horiz_container_outer_55_offer_-1`. Some browsers will make all elements accessible by their `ID` like that, but it's not recommended.

The reason it doesn't work in your specific case is that what you've written is not a valid javascript variable name. Your attempt to access a variable will be interpreted as

```
dw_scrollObj.col.horiz_container_outer_55_offer_ - 1
```

If you would instead access your object by

```
document.getElementById('dw_scrollObj.col.horiz_container_outer_55_offer_-1')
```

or

```
$('#dw_scrollObj.col.horiz_container_outer_55_offer_-1')
```

you would not have this same problem.

For your `setInterval` code, that would mean

```
this.timerId = setInterval("$('#" + this.animString + "').scroll()", 10);
```

or preferably

```
this.timerId = setInterval(function() {
   $('#' + this.animString).scroll();
}, 10);
```

If your code is in a loop, where `animString` will change over time, inside the context, you will need to create a new closure:

```
this.timerId = setInterval((function(x) {
    return function() {
       $('#'+x).scroll();
    };
})(this.animString), 10);
```

Comment: I understand the concept behind your idea and ThiefMaster's answer too, but this doesn't work

Comment: I've updated with all (in turn) your snippet suggestions, but i can't understand why it does not work.

Comment: well I was addressing a specific problem with the code you've posted, at the place where you said it was breaking. There may be other parts of your code that are having similar or other issues. What error messages are you seeing now that you've implemented the above change?

Comment: No,I don't see any error messages but behaviour of my scroll isn't activated

Comment: That could be for any number of reasons. Now that we've fixed the initial problem, I don't think your issue is in any part of the code that you've included in your question. There is not enough information here to say what the exact problem is. If the snippet you've copied used `setInterval` the way you've included it, then there's a fair chance that the entire plugin is poorly coded, and there's no limit to the number of things that could be causing it to malfunction.

Comment: Yes i perfectly understand. I suppose that, from now, i'll try to code different "id" for avoiding those cases that will create that kind of problem. In future, i'll take a depth look into code for try to understand what's the real problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `setInterval` snippet breaks because the string you pass to `setInterval` is evaluated as JavaScript. It becomes

```
dw_scrollObj.col.horiz_container_outer_55_offer_-1.scroll()
```

but a hyphen (`-`) is not valid in identifiers.

E.g. this throws an error

```
var some-name = 'foo';
```