# Retrieve list of Instagram pictures by Hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

I have 2 questions:

1) I'm trying to retrieve a list of posts from Instagram via javascript but I keep getting errors:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/lion/?__a=1',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                       
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                 });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The error I get:

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement[Learn More]

If I change jsonp to json:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked

How can I overcome this problem?

2)Is it maybe not allowed to get data for my site from the url https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/lion/?__a=1 ? (maybe they consider it like scraping?)

I have tried to check the official api page but it sounds like only users who have an instagram account and are logged in would be able to see the contents of the feed after retrieving an oauth2 token.

EDIT:
Seems like that to send a request to this url i need jsonp but since I'm not getting the answer in a proper format I'm not sure how can I make this request work. (There isn't already a question like this on stackoverflow about Instagram. The API has recently changed so I'm trying to find a workaround).

Comment: The above code does not produce the error you specified. *identifier starts immediately after numeric literal* is [likely an error somewhere else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883397/javascript-firebug-error-identifier-starts-immediately-after-numeric-literal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript Firebug error: Identifier starts immediately after numeric literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883397/javascript-firebug-error-identifier-starts-immediately-after-numeric-literal)

Comment: Hi @Liam, yes you are right, after re-checking my code i found the problem was actually different. I'm fixing the question now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Instagram Developers Documentation you should pass a valid access token on the URL using the `?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` parameter.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

Try removing `dataType: 'jsonp'` from your AJAX request to get the actual error response from Instagram

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I get without jsonp is: Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Comment: About the access token. I don't think it would make much sense if to see a public list of posts every user needs to insert his own login credentials. What if one of the visitors of my site doesn't have an Instagram account?

Comment: yes, that is because Instagram is not processing your request due to the missing access_token. The only way to get content from Instagram is passing that parameter, without proper authentication your request won't be accepted. For them it is a way to prevent any website to display their content without previous registration.

Comment: Can you link me to the document from where you have taken that API endpoint ? it looks like a deprecated api

Comment: @BlackBurn027 yes indeed it could be deprecated since i found it here on stackoverflow, but I can't find anything official on their site to obtain the same result.

Comment: As per my understanding your requirement is to fetch the public posts with #lion in it am i correct ?

Comment: @BlackBurn027 yes exactly. I would like to ask the users on my site to publish pictures on instagram with a certain hashtag and have those listed on my homepage. I'm also not sure if instagram is allowing us to do that...

Comment: Looks like instagram has recently tightened their privacy terms over api, they are expecting us to have an registered client app in their developer site.